# Order articles by Popularity

Tags: entries, orderby

I want to have a kind of 'trending' or 'most popular' area on my homepage which lists the top 10 most popular articles.

Is there a simple way to order entries by popularity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure - first you need to [track views](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/entry_tracking.html) in order to determine popularity. So on your "single entry" templates, add `track_views="one"` to your `channel:entries` tag.

Then, you can use `orderby="view_count_one"` on your `channel:entries` listings tags.

Answer (score 1):

### View Count + Total Comments

You can also use the variable {comment_total} in conjunction with {view_count_one} for an alternate assessment of popularity.

On the `exp:channel:entries` listing tag

```
orderby="view_count_one|comment_total"
```

**Conditional might be**

```
{if comment_total >= '10' AND view_count_one >= '10' }
This entry is trending
{if:else}
This is a regular entry
{/if}
```